# Package Acro greek letter

Tags: greek, acro

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{MCP-1}{
  short = MCP-1 ,
  long  = Monocyte Chemoattractant Protein-1 ,
  class = abbrev
}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

I would like to add a greek sign to my abbreviations with the acro package, somehow like this:

```
\DeclareAcronym{MCP-1}{
  short = MCP-1 \alpha ,
  long  = Monocyte Chemoattractant Protein-1 ,
  class = abbrev
}
```

However this creates only errors. I have tried all different kinds of writing greek letters, but all do not work. 
Does anybody have a answer for this question?

Comment: `$\alpha$`, perhaps?

Comment: This shows alpha in the abbreviation list but unfortunately alpha is - unlike the other letters in the abbreviation - not printed bold.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with the inclusion of the `textgreek` package and using `\textalpha` to insert an alpha symbol.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\DeclareAcronym{MCP-1}{
  short = MCP-1 \textalpha,
  long  = Monocyte Chemoattractant Protein-1 ,
  class = abbrev
}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\ac{MCP-1}
\end{document}
```

This will result in the following Abbreviation list:
[image: Output of MWE]